Service connection not found in the project
Someone from my team has deleted a bunch of a DevOps project service connections, and now when I try to run our pipeline it says:
"Service connection 3284f354-71a6-4839-ba91-REDACTED not found in the project f9b79625-2860-4d92-a4ee-REDACTED."

I have no reference of what these guids mean, how can I correlate these with the project configuration? Basically I understand I need to recreate some service connection, but I have no idea which one just by looking at the guid. My pipeline yaml is:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/build/.vsts-ci.yml
Run a DevOps pipeline that was previously working.

I think the YML file you linked has been adapted in your DevOps project, because there's no service connection referenced in it. Try grab the yml as it is in devops instead.


I have no reference of what these guids mean, how can I correlate these with the project configuration?

Service connection's are created automatically when running the pipeline and connecting to any Azure resource, These service connections are referenced in Azure AD as Azure AD application or Service Principal.

The guid is the Azure AD Client ID:-

You can click on Manage Service principal to get routed to Azure AD application.

You can also create a manual Azure Resource manager service connection with Azure AD service principal details.

Powershell service principal in Azure AD:-

If the service connections are deleted the underlying Azure AD service principal is also deleted along with it. You will have to create new Service connection and use it in your Azure Devops pipeline.

Unfortunately the UI is really not fully helpful, you need to shoot to all directions a little bit to figure out what the error is.
I ended up trying to inspect the yaml in the pipeline, and it failed to connect to github. That's where I verified that the service connection to GitHub was created by someone that is no longer in our org, so the service principal deleted might have been associated with that account. After I recreated the service principal and re-authorized, the pipeline got access to GH again.

I understand, You can suggest your points as a feature request for Azure devops here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/provide-feedback?view=azure-devops to improve UI
